# what is a container? and gVisor?

Tags: security, virtual-machine, virtualization, linux-containers

I am trying to understand what are containers and what is their purpose?

I am a little bit confused. When I started to read about them I saw that they rely on the Linux namespaces (is it true?) - a way to isolate the process within the container from the other processes on the machine, and got the impression that their main purpose is security.

For instance, let's say that I own a server that runs multiple services. I also don't want that a single hacked service will be able to hack the whole system. So I put each service inside a container that will make the service unable to interfere the other processes inside the machine, like to kill them or to play with their memory and in that way eliminate the risk.

But later I saw other purposes like being able to ship the app easily? or something like that. so what is their main purpose? I also read that if their main purpose is security - they have a problem. because they run directly on the host kernel (again, is it true?)- and an exploit like the "dirty cow" will or was able to get out of the container and be able to corrupt the machine. So I ended reading about the gVisor - which from what I understood tries to secure the containers, and in some cases succeed. So - what does gVisor do differently? that it's able to secure the containers? is gVisor a container itself? or just a Runtime environment for containers?

eventually, I always see comparisons between containers and VM and I ask why? And when should I use them?

I don't know if anything that I wrote is correct, and I will be glad if you will point out my mistakes, and answer my questions. Yes, I know that there are a lot of them and I am sorry, but Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> The answer below is not guaranteed to be concise. Anyone is welcomed to point out my mistakes.

It might be a little bit vague because many people mixed such concepts nowadays.

### 1. LXC

When I first got to know such concepts, *container* still meant [LXC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC), a long-existed technique in Linux. IMHO, container is a complete process that does not simulate a kernel. The difference between a container and a normal process is that container provides a isolated *view* via cgroups, as if it was in a new operating system. But in fact, the containers still share the host kernel (you are right), so people do worry about the security, especially when you want to deploy it in a public cloud (I don't see people using LXC directly on public cloud yet).

Despite the potential insecurity, the convenience and lightweightness(fast boot, small memory fingerprint) of containers seem to outweigh its drawbacks in most of security-insensitive situations. Tools like docker and kubernetes make large-scale deployment and management more efficient.

### 2. Virtual Machine & Hardware-assisted virtualization

In contrast to container, the concept *Virtual Machine* represents another category of isolated execution environment. Considering that most of VMs leverages some hardware-accelerating techniques like VT-x, I will assume you are talking about **hardware-assisted virtualization**. Virtual Machine **usually contains a full kernel inside it**.

See this picture from [Doug Chamberlain](https://blog.netapp.com/blogs/containers-vs-vms/)
[image]

The [Intel VT-x technique](https://superuser.com/questions/939340/what-is-vt-x-why-it-is-not-enabled-in-few-machine-by-default) provides 2 modes, *root mode*(privileged) and *non-root mode*(not privileged). Each mode has its own ring0-ring3 (e.g, non-root ring3, non-root ring0, root ring3, root ring 0). The whole virtual machine runs in non-root mode, and the hypervisor(VMM, e.g., kvm) runs in root-mode.

In the classic qemu+kvm setup, qemu runs in root ring3, and kvm runs in root ring0.

The strong isolation and the existance of guest kernel makes virtual machine more secure and compatible. But, of course, the price is performance and efficiency (slower boot etc.)

### Container-based Virtualization

People want the isolation of hardware-assisted virtualization, but don't want to give up the convenience of containers. Therefore, the hybrid solution seems really intuitive to come.

There are 2 typical solutions at present, [Kata Container](https://katacontainers.io/) and [gVisor][6]

Kata Container tries to slim the whole stack of virtual machine to make it more lightweight. However, **there is still linux inside it and it is still a virtual machine**, but more lightweight.

gVisor claims to be an secure container, but it **still leverages hardware virtualization techniques (or ptrace if you don't want virtualization)**. There is a component called *sentry*, which runs both in non-root ring0 and root ring3. The sentry will do part of the guest kernel's job, but is much smaller than linux. If sentry could not finish a request itself, it proxy the request down to the host kenrel.

The reason why most people believe gvisor is somewhat more secure is that it achieves "defense in depth" -- more layers of indirection lead people to believe it is more secure. This is usually true, but again, is not a guarantee.